# Accessing a line after it is painted

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

This question has already been asked by someone else but i've not got a clear answer.

I have created a Line class and paint method for it to draw a line.

I want to know how we can access the line after it is painted.  I have two JLabels that mark the end points of the line.  So i can able to resize the line using them but i cannot select that line.

I have also tried creating a panel around the line and added mouseListener to it but it is not very efficient.

Can anyone suggest a smarter way?

Here is the constructor for the line

```
 public Line(Point a,Point b,JLabel l1,JLabel l2){
    this(a,b);
    this.l1=l1;
    this.l2=l2;
    this.addMouseListener(this);
 }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Create `Line2D` object. Then use `BasicStroke` and define desired thickness of the line. 
Use the method

```
public Shape createStrokedShape(Shape s)
```

to get the Line's stroked shape.
The use `contains()` method of the Line `Shape` to check whether click point is on line.

Comment: I think `contains` is always false for `Line2D`.

Answer (score 2):

@StanislavL has the right idea to use the `contains()` method of a class that implements [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html), but @Catalina observes that it's always false for [`Line2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html). Instead, render the endpoints using a `Shape` with a non-empty boundary. For example, [`GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) uses a `Rectangle` to allow dragging each endpoint.

[image: GraphPanel]

Comment: Yes, and your example illustrates the benefit of `RenderingHints`!

Answer (score 0):

From the few lines that you posted, I cannot decide what you actually have. Selection of lines is not something that is ready. You need to implement it, but it is easy.
Anyway, you should keep the coordinates of the line and check in the mouse listener for mouse clicks over the line.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ev) 
{
  double TOLERANCE = 5;   // Small tolerance measured in pixels

  if (ev.getClickCount() == 1)
  {
    Point cursor = ev.getPoint();

    if (Math.abs(cursor.x - a.x) < TOLERANCE && 
        Math.abs(cursor.y - a.y) < TOLERANCE)
    {
      // Clicked on the first point
    }
    else if (Math.abs(cursor.x - b.x) < TOLERANCE && 
             Math.abs(cursor.y - b.y) < TOLERANCE)
    {
      // Clicked on the second point
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your Line from JComponent or one proper successor class (ie. JButton)

Then override the contains function;

```
Shape shape;   
public boolean contains(int x, int y) {   
    // If the button has changed size, make a new shape object.   
    if (shape == null || !shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {   
        shape = new Line2D.Float(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);   
    }   
    return shape.contains(x, y);   
}
```

Note: The Line2D.Float constructor parameters might be unordered, I wrote that from memory.