# JScrollPane doesn't work.. Why?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane

I've a Frame which has two internal frames. I create a 'Board' object which is an instance of Board class. Board class extends JPanel.

```
class Layout extends JFrame{
   Dimension dimen=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   public initializeWindows(){
       JInternalFrame dev=new JInternalFrame("Devices",true,true,false,false);
       JInternalFrame cir=new JInternalFrame("Circuit",true,true,false,false);
       Board b=new Board();
       cir.add(b);
       JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(b);
       this.add(dev);
       this.add(cir);

       dev.setVisible(true);
       dev.setSize(150,650);
       dev.setLocation(0,100);
       dev.pack();

       inf.setVisible(true);
       inf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(dimen.width*0.88),(int)(dimen.height*0.75)));
       inf.setLocation(150,100);
       inf.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
       inf.pack();

   }
```

But the scrollpane does not appear.  Why is tat??

Comment: Add the `ScrollPane`. For example: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddcomponenttoJScrollPane.htm

Comment: You should add your scroll object to your JFrame by calling this.add(scroll).

Comment: Why did you add code that **could not compile?**  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  But then I just realized that has been ***mentioned to you [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767652/accessing-a-line-after-it-is-painted).***

Comment: Sorry @AndrewThompson.. Mine is a big project.. and i tried my best to make it an SSCCE.. i will post something tat can compile..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not adding the `JScrollPane` to the internal frame.

You are actually adding the `Board` to the `JInternalFrame cir` and to the `JScrollPane` while you should do something like

```
JInternalFrame cir=new JInternalFrame("Circuit",true,true,false,false);
Board b=new Board();
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(b);
cir.add(scroll)
this.add(cir);
```

Comment: I want the board object inside the 'cir'.. and i added cir.add(scroll).. but it is still not visible..

Answer (score 1):

please set `cir.setVisible(true)` and `cir.add(scroll)` instead of `cir.add(b);`

If you want your scroll bars to be visible all times you can use

```
scroll = JScrollPane(b,
  ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
  ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS)
```